# Trouble running android command in command line

Tags: android, command-line, cordova

I've set up my paths to point to the Android SDK tools via this command:

```
# Cordova command line tools for Android SDK ----------------------
export PATH=${PATH}:/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools:/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/tools
```

When I echo out the $PATH, this is what I get:

```
/Users/lorenzoignacio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin:/Users/lorenzoignacio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/bin:/Users/lorenzoignacio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin:/Users/lorenzoignacio/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/Users/lorenzoignacio/.local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools:/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/tools
```

If you look at the end of it, you see my path:

```
/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools:/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/tools
```

And yet when I try to run the  `cordova platform add android`  I get:

```
[Error: The command `android` failed. Make sure you have the latest Android SDK installed, and the `android` command (inside the tools/ folder) added to your path. Output: /bin/sh: android: command not found]
```

The entire adt-bundle is located in my root user directory in a directory called `Development`. The exact path is `/Users/me/Development/adt-bundle/`

What Am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What Am I missing?

You are missing two `~` characters, perhaps.

> The exact path is /Users/me/Development/adt-bundle/

That's not what you typed into your `PATH`. Your `PATH` says that there is no `/Users/me` -- instead, `PATH` is expecting a `/Development` directory *in the root of your volume*.

Now, in Linux, the solution would be to add a `~` to indicate that `/Development` is relative to your home directory:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:~/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools:~/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/tools
```

My OS X shell experience is rusty, so I forget if `~` will map to `/Users/me` or not. If it does, use `~`, otherwise, go with:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/me/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/me/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/tools
```

Comment: Still having trouble unfortunately... Any other issues, do you think?

Comment: @iggy2012: Did you restart your Terminal window or otherwise ensure that your `PATH` change is in effect?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @CommonsWare for helping me out with my $PATH issues.

In addition to the solution, it turns out that the latest ADT only contains Android Target 18.

Phonegap v3.0.9 seems to run Android Target 17, so I downloaded that and it now works wonderfully.